# TFS vNext Powershell build step is using older version of Powershell module

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

a build with Powershell++ (it comes from [Extension Utilities Pack](https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack)) step keeps failing when I try to run task containing following code `Copy-Item -FromSession $cs` to copy items from different machine. The error message is

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FromSession'.

However, the code does not fail when run from PS console when I'm logged to that machine.

Then I included

```
(get-command copy-item).Version.ToString()
(get-command copy-item).ModuleName.ToString()
```

And got version 3.1.0.0 and module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management in PS console and 3.0.0.0 in TFS build step output (module is the same). The version of Powershell is identical in both - 5.0.10586.117.

Looks like the Powershell that is running inside TFS is using different modules.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VSTS or TFS on-premise? Do you install it on Hosted build agent or load it on Windows agent?

Comment: Also, did you try to use another agent machine? It seems there is not set module in the Powershell++ task: https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack/tree/master/Utilites/Powershell%2B%2B

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem was not exactly related to that task. However the version used is still confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me for not knowing enough about Powershell providers. When wildcard was included in the source path I got this error, without the wildcard it worked fine.

The `FromSession` parameter is available in PS v5 and not limited to Microsoft.PowerShell.Management 3.0.0.0 (but that is still a mystery to me).